# BouncyCastle - Generate certificate file that MS Windows understands

Tags: java, windows, x509certificate, bouncycastle, digital-certificate

I'm using Java and BouncyCastle to generate a CA certificate, the CA issues several user Certificates, these Certificates are stored on a Data Base with their private key. How can I generate a certificate file that can be installed by Windows in which the operating system recognizes the private key and the certificate details ?
If I save the certificate details from X509Certificate class to PEM file the certificate details are recognized but without the private key.

Any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: For Windows clients you should use CertEnroll COM interfaces family: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374850(v=vs.85).aspx. Keep in mind that private key should be generated on target client only. It is a very bad practice when keys are generated on CA server and only then reach target clients.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I generate the Certificate file contents ? Is there anyway to pack everything together on the same file ?

Comment: Certificate content is constructed by an issuing CA server. You generate request, submit to CA server, retrieve and install issued certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you generate a private key and a certificate signing request, you send the csr to the CA, and the CA issues the certificate. Finally you can generate a `keystore` and store the private key and the certificate together on it. So I don't understand how is your CA storing the private key in a data base since the private key is not send to the CA.

Omitting this information (maybe you've a selfsigned CA for infrastructure purposes, data base it's not safe to store privateKeys, etc), the thing is; to load a private key and a certificate on windows you need a `keystore` file (typically for windows a `pfx` or `pkcs12`) instead of only a certificate. To do so using java and bouncycastle as you ask you can use the follow sample code (as you said I suppose that you have the certificate and the private key):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // generate your certificate
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509", new BouncyCastleProvider());
        Certificate yourCert = cf.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("C:/your_certificate_path"));
        // here you can add also the issuer of your cert
        Certificate[] certChain = { yourCert };
        // depending on your private key format you've a different
        // ways to parse its
        Key privatekey = null;//...
        String alias = "yourKSEntry";
        // generate the keystore
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", new BouncyCastleProvider());
        // necessary to init a new keystore
        ks.load(null, null);
        String keyPass = null;// your key pass or null if the key file has no password
        // adds the key and cert to the keystore
        ks.setKeyEntry(alias, privatekey, null, certChain);
        // save to file in order that then you
        // can install on windows keystore
        ks.store(new FileOutputStream("C:/where_save_your_keystore.p12"), "your_keystore_pass".toCharArray());

    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: @maluk nice to help you :)